# Prawn PDF Inline Color Helper Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn, string-interpolation

So I'm using Prawn PDF gem for my rails application and I'm trying to write a helper method for part of a text string to be black when the rest of the string is blue, the reason I'm trying to write a helper is because this will be used for many different fields. Not sure if Prawn supports this but I've been giving it a shot.

**`text string`**

```
pad_bottom(5) { text "Owner: #{inline_black_helper(@order.first.owner)}", align: :center, inline_format: true, color: blue, size: 16 }
```

**`inline_black_helper`**

```
def inline_black_helper(text)
  "<color rbg='000000'>#{text}</color>"
end
```

**Aka the same as doing**

```
pad_bottom(5) { text "Owner: <color rbg='000000'>#{@order.first.owner}</color>", align: :center, inline_format: true, color: blue, size: 16 }
```

Obviously the last example works fine but as stated, since this will be used for many fields, having to write `<color rbg='000000'>..</color>` 50 times seems very 'un-rails' to me. This current implementation doesn't raise and error and the actual information is interpolating correctly but  the entire `text` is blue instead of the first part being blue and the desired `@order.first.owner` being black. Any insight is appreciated as always, thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to do rgb instead of rbg?

Comment: wwoooowww I swear I looked at that too before I posted to make sure it wasn't something silly. Welp, I got nothing to say on that one cause it literally works perfectly now. Maybe this will help someone in the future. Thanks much @NickM

Comment: Cool. Then I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper is wrong. You need:

`<color rgb='000000'>`

You currently have `rbg`

Comment: You deserve the answer rep! haha

Comment: Ahem, 'rgb'.  :-)